# Unity iOS Build Best Practice

Tags: ios, security, unity-game-engine, build

So I need to send someone an iOS project made through unity. I wanted to know if there are any security flaws in the built application.

If I send someone these files (not compiled ipa from xcode, the files unity gives me) could they reverse engineer it and find my code?

Are there any specific player settings that could minimize this risk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I send someone these files (not compiled ipa from xcode, the files
>   unity gives me) could they reverse engineer it and find my code?

Yes. You are generating Xcode project files and some of the scripts and resources are visible and can easily be modified.

> Are there any specific player settings that could minimize this risk?

You can make it harder to modify your script. Setting the Scripting Backend to Mono produces managed code which can easily be viewed with software like ILSpy and can be modified by other programs too.

Changing the the Scripting Backend to IL2CPP makes it harder to view and temper with the code but it can still be done if the person spends more time to reverse it.

---

If you really don't want to expose your app easily, don't share your Unity project, don't share the Xcode project. If all you want is for the other person to test the app, build the Xcode project and share the **.ipa** file. You can also share the build with the other person through *iTunes Connect*.